# SAPUI5 Cordova start native android navigation

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sapui5, whitelist

I wrote a javascript function that calls the native android Google navigation from a cordova application but I don't know which **cordova whitelist declaration** I must use to start the navigation application.

Is start the navigation from a **SAPUI5** application with **the following code**

```
sap.m.URLHelper.redirect("google.navigation" + ":"+ "q=Ericusspitze 1, 20457 Hamburg");
```

When I use the following whitelist declaration(not recommended) in the cordova `config.xml` the navigation app **starts correctly**.

`<access origin="*" launch-external="yes" />`

If I only use the following whitelist declaration in the cordova `config.xml` the navigation **doesn't start**

`<access origin="google.navigation:*" launch-external="yes" />`

`<access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes" />`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make intent whitelist and not just Network Request Whitelist.

So add the following:

**Network Request Whitelist**

```
<!-- Access to the subdomain maps.google.com -->
<access origin="http://maps.google.com" />

<!-- Access to all the subdomains on google.com -->
<access origin="http://*.google.com" />
```

so you can't use colon(`:`) for giving access to the network requests

I believe you are trying to give access to intent.If that's true,

**Intent Whitelist**

```
<!-- Allow geo: links to open maps -->
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

Read more about [Cordova-plugin-whitelist here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)

Comment: the network request whitelist declarations doesn't work. Even when I use <access origin="*" /> the navigation app doesn't start if I not using <access origin="*" launch-external="yes" /> The Intent Whitelist doesn't work for me but I don't call the navigation app with a href but with sap.m.URLHelper.redirect("google.navigation" + ":"+ "q=Ericusspitze 1, 20457 Hamburg");